# Sense net download sn-evaluation-webpi-6.4.0.7114.zip not working on following steps

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sensenet

I have downloaded "sn-evaluation-webpi-6.4.0.7114.zip" from this [link](http://sensenet.codeplex.com/)  and follow the steps as given in this [link](http://wiki.sensenet.com/index.php?title=How_to_install_Sense/Net_from_web_deployment_package_IIS_7.5_and_IIS_7.0)
Also I have configured

```
Visual studio 2010
MS 2008 r2
IIS 7.5
```

in my machine
but following all the steps at last it is not browsing on making it as virtual

Also on following the link step at **step:8** I founded that there is an issue in getting the permission.
I am getting only permission as "Grant Permissions(SenseNet6WebPI) "

[image]

instead of

[image]

There is a difference in permission on looking to the image and also its not running on browsing on configuring it to the virtual.

please reply what else I have to do?

Comment: This should be moved to ServerFault.

Comment: Have you made sure the full pre-requisites are installed (server features and .NET)?  http://wiki.sensenet.com/index.php?title=Software_Requirements_for_Production_Environment

Comment: Also, you have selected app pools, whereas it seems to want an actual site.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne thanks for replieng I have installed the software as I had describe in my question.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne how to select app pools, I have follow all the steps as given the describe link, so in that 1 issue i am facing is that on step 8 i m not getting all permission and without all permission also i m able to follow step 9 and so on, but atlast on browsing i m gettion error of iis7 on browser. the sensenet is an actual site  as seen in the image

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair moved to serverfault, will you please elaborate sir

Comment: What I am saying, is it looks like you have selected the "app pools" in the tree, instead of actually selecting the site you want to install this at, i.e. under "Sites".

Comment: @AnthonyHorne actually I am importing this in site only as suggest in the referred document, in taking p-screen of Image I might have mistaken.

Comment: Any Answer please ??

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you what you are doing wrong. It appears that you are trying to import the Sense/Net package into the Application Pool (server level), and it must be imported into a Site.

Under the "Sites" folder right-click on the "sensenet" site and import it there using the "Deploy" then "Import Application..." menu choices as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Here I have selected sensenet, see down having the header "Name", down there I have selected sensenet, from there also we can deploy and import the application.

Comment: @Xtremcool You may be experiencing an older MS bug which was supposedly fixed with later versions of WebDeploy  (see this link: https://forums.iis.net/t/1169043.aspx) Make sure WebDeploy is the latest version.